# Can't connect XtraReport to Firebird Database

Tags: devexpress, firebird, xtrareport, firebird-.net-provider

I'd like to create an XtraReport connected  to a Firebird database. Actually I have done this before, with no problem. But in this new project when I create the connection I get the error "Could not load type Firebird.Data.FirebirdClient.FBConnection".

The Firebird client dll is a reference in this project. It was not added through NuGet because my version of Visual Studio does not accept the new version of the Nuget Package Manager. I just put the dll in the same folder as the project EXE and added the reference.

All the other database functions are working correctly in the project, the only problem is with the XtraReport connection.

This might be something related to an installation issue in the computer or Visual Studio, because when I copy a project (in which the creation of such report was ok) from another computer to this one, it does not work anymore, although if I run the project a previously created report runs and is correctly exhibited.

I'm using Devexpress 16.1.18, and Firebird client 7.10.1.

So I'd like to know if there's some step in the process I'm skipping or overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought, it was something I was missing. After I installed the Firebird dll using gacutil (following DevExpress support instructions) everything worked out fine. Simple as that.

Comment: this is somewhat strange. Since you mentioned NuGet i think you mean C# and .Net, not a native code apps. And .Net Provider i heared was capable of "WireProtocol" thus would not need `fbclient.dll`

Comment: @Arioch'The I think they're referring to the C# `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll` (the Firebird ADO.net provider library), and not `fbclient.dll`.

Comment: Thank you all for your input, but the issue has been solved. The report designer can't find FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll in the project's output directory, only in the GAC folder. After installing the dll using gacutil.exe I was able to connect the XtraReport to the database without any trouble.

Comment: what about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66647272/threadsafedatalayer-and-idatalayer-devexpress-xpo-cant-map-classinfo-to-same-ta